# How can angularjs route transitions be animated interactively?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation

I know how to animate between routes, but how can these animations be made "interactive"? For example, rather than simply triggering a preset slide animation on swipe, I would like the animation to map directly to the user's drag gesture. Another side effect of this type of interaction is that a user should be able to start a transition, but then cancel it using the same gesture.

This sort of pattern seems important for building the sort of animated transitions seen in Google's Material Design. I can accomplish these transitions within a route, but for organizational reasons I would like to be able to do so between routes.

Any examples or descriptions of designs would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this :

1. Detect touchstart event and trigger behaviour
2. detect the finger position while moving, and shift your wrapper html element accordingly. Probably with css, like transform3d: translateX( ... )
3. on touchend, evaluate if the distance is enough to trigger route change
4. if not, animate back to original position with css transition.

You probably want to have a look at http://hammerjs.github.io/ for gesture detection.

Good luck !

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my question isn't regarding how to build a swipe interaction, but how to do so with angularjs route transitions. Typical examples of swiping between routes use ng-enter and leave class targets. They don't demonstrate how to build interactive transitions.